# Authentication with Architecture Components MVVM, passing token from Repository to ViewModel

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, basic-authentication, android-architecture-components

I want to make an login activity based the "official" MVVM, Repository model.

I have looked at the Android Studio "Login" template and somewhat understood how that works. The flow chart below shows how I plan the data flow between classes. The template did not include the WebService part, instead the token was immediately return without a callback.

[image: Login Flow Chart]

Since creating references (in callbacks) to the VM/Activity is bad practice, what are the options for having the token propagated back to the VM (represented by the dashed arrows)?

Notes:

1. From the VM to Activity, data is passed using LiveData. I understand that step.
2. I thought about creating LiveData in the Repository, which is then observed in the Activity, skipping the VM. However, surely some logic might need to be done on any data coming from the Repository, so it should first pass through the VM, be processed there and then a derived result observed by the Activity.
3. It seems difficult to use LiveData to pass data from the Repository to the VM because any call to .observe() in the VM needs a suitable Context. It seems only the Activity can .observe?
4. To get a better understanding, I would prefer to avoid the use of RxJava and Dagger for now and to work in Java.

Thanks

Comment: This illustation rocks! You are drawing these for every method you getting used to? If yes, can you share some? I would really be happy to see some more about MVVM and DI. Also, why don't you use Kotlin? Moving to Kotlin from Java is painless process, things just become easy in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `LiveData` inside the repository. Instead, you can make a call from the VM to the `repository.login(u,p)` and wait for the results to arrive. Once the results has arrived, just update the `LiveData` instance inside the VM.

The network call must be done asynchronously anyway, or you can make use of the callback mechanism from the networking libraries like Retrofit.

Your `ViewModel` will look like this (pseudo code):

```
class LoginViewModel: ViewModel{

    LiveData<Result> login(String username, String password){

        LiveData<Result> resultLiveData = new MutableLiveData<Result>();

        // Let it be an async. call from Retrofit
        Repository.login(username, password, new Callback<Result>{
            void onResult(Result result){
                resultLiveData.value = result  // update the livedata.
            }
        }

        return resultLiveData;

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but it looks like you have this instantiated anonymous class `new Callback<Result>` . This gets forwarded to the Repository, then to the Datasource which then calls `call.enqueue(forwardedObject)` (for Retrofit)?

Comment: Yes. Then the repository class call the call.enqueue(forwardedObject) for Retrofit.

Comment: @xenull Yes, exactly as @Zakaria said here. When `call.enque()` returns, the Datasource will call the callback provided by the Repository, and then the Repository will call the `new Callback<Result>` inside the ViewModel.

Anyway, the code is neither Kotlin nor Java, it's just pseudocode only.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to fully understand the order of the calls and scope by testing. Despite some research I never came across this pattern, and I did not think the callback would have access to variables within the vm. Perhaps it is like an inner class.

Comment: For reference the most helpful article to list ways to pass data from Repo to VM that I found was [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) but even that did not seem to mention your method (three options, listed two-thirds the way down)

Comment: Thanks for the above link. While the answer does make sense for one particular case, how would you share authenticated/not authenticated status across multiple screens with such approach.